# uniq -c in one column

Tags: shell, unix, awk, uniq

Imagine we have a txt file like the next one:

**Input:**

```
a1 D1
b1 D1
c1 D1
a1 D2
a1 D3
c1 D3
```

I want to count the time each element in the first column appears but also keep the information provided by the second column (someway). Potential possible output formats are represented, but any coherent alternative is also accepted:

**Possible output 1:**

```
3 a1 D1,D2,D3
1 b1 D1
2 c1 D1,D3
```

**Possible output 2:**

```
3 a1 D1
1 b1 D1
2 c1 D1
3 a1 D2
3 a1 D3
1 c1 D3
```

How can I do this? I guess a combination `sort -k 1 input | uniq -c <keep col2>` or perhaps using `awk` but I was not able to write anything that works. However, all answers are considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
a1 D1
b1 D1
c1 D1
a1 D2
a1 D3
c1 D3
```

then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]+=1;next}{print arr[$1],$0}' file.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
3 a1 D1
1 b1 D1
2 c1 D1
3 a1 D2
3 a1 D3
2 c1 D3
```

Explanation: 2-pass solution (observe that `file.txt` is repeated), first pass does count number of occurences of first column value storing that data into array `arr`, second pass is for printing computed number from array, followed by whole line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    {
        vals[$1] = ($1 in vals ? vals[$1] "," : "") $2
        cnts[$1]++
    }
    END {
        for (key in vals) {
            print cnts[key], key, vals[key]
        }
    }
' file
3 a1 D1,D2,D3
1 b1 D1
2 c1 D1,D3
```